# Cannot resolve symbol Request

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-app-requests

I have get error cannot resolve Request. Which library should I import?

```
new Request(
    session,
    "/{user-id}/taggable_friends",
    null,
    HttpMethod.GET,
    new Request.Callback() {
        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
            /* handle the result */
        }
    }
).executeAsync();
```

Comment: Facing same problem :(

Comment: Depends on what version of the Android SDK you are referencing. If you're using the 4.x versions, you should be using GraphRequest: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/graph/#userdata

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment so sorry for the answer.

I am also new to Android programming and I believe that in the new Facebook SDK that sessions was taken out so this maybe why it is not working.

Check the changelog to be certain and your version of facebook sdk, mine is v4.0

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/androidsdk/request